# Проблема в простейшем алгоритме переворота строки: error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь реализовать простейший алгоритм переворота строки,но не могу т.к выскакивает ошибка - error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope.Сразу прошу прощения за тупость вопроса,но я правда не могу понять,что тут не так.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    char string[] = "Hello, world";
    int length = strlen(string);
    int temp,i,j;
    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++,j--)
    {
        temp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[j];
        string[j] = temp;
    }
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Спасибо огромное,недочет глупый

Comment: `sizeof(string)`

Answer (score 1):

А писать

```
#include <string.h>
```

Страуструп будет?!...

Ну, или хотя бы

```
#include <cstring>
```

и `std::strlen()`...

Comment: И вам огромное спасибо,буду в следующий раз внимательнее

Comment: Не наоборот: "<cstring> или хотя бы <string.h>" ?